# phpStorm, xdebug: is there a way to exclude certain directories from debugging?

Tags: xdebug, phpstorm

When I'm debugging, I would like to exclude certain directories - for example, every time a class is instantiated, my debugger steps into Doctrine's ClassLoader::loadClass() which is annoying... I tried adding those directories I want to exclude in Settings / PHP / Debug / Skipped Paths, but that doesn't help...

Comment: "Skipped Paths" is a different thing -- check these tickets for explanation: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-8572 ; http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-5732 . As far as I understand there is no such functionality available (unless you will use "Run until cursor" or "Run until return" -- but that's easy to mess up). I guess you need this ticket, but currently it has no planned version: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-4722

Comment: That's what I figured... thanks!

Comment: You may want to have a look into Step Filters feature: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.3/step-filters.html

Comment: PhpStorm 2017.1.1 includes both function and file excludes for debugging: https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2017/03/phpstorm-2017-1-1-eap-171-4073/

Comment: **As of 2018 the answer by [TheFrost](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53051045/343302) is the correct answer.**

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Xdebug does not support skipping directories while either debugging or profiling yet. This is something that I want to add. There is a feature request at http://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=901. It seems Jetbrains also has a ticket for this: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-4722

Comment: +1 for the definitive answer. @Derick - yep, this would be a good feature for the next version of xdebug; the same problem comes up when working with pretty much any framework or CMS. The only way around at the moment it is to set a breakpoint at the start of one's own code, and switch off the 'break immediately' option.

Comment: Added a ticket to Xdebug as well now.

Comment: Thank you Derick. Both for the answer, and for xdebug ))

Comment: I noticed this was marked as "resolved - won't fix". Is it possible to get an update here on the reasoning/progress? :)

Comment: For the record: It was added in PHPStorm.

Answer (score 14):

What I found in PhpStorm (I don't know since which version it's there - mine now is 2018.1): 
`Lanugage & Frameworks > PHP > Debug > Step Filters`.

For Symfony 4, these `Skipped Methods` brought peace to debugging:

- `Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->findFileWithExtension`
- `Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->findFile`
- `Symfony\Component\Debug\DebugClassLoader->loadClass`
- `Symfony\Component\Debug\DebugClassLoader->checkClass`
- `Symfony\Component\Debug\DebugClassLoader->getOwnInterfaces`

Comment: This is best answer as far.

Comment: `Step Filters` is the right answer. It prevents the breakpoint from ever triggering what's in the filters, be it a method or a file.

Answer (score 8):

That function does exist on PHP Storm 2016.2

Under `Languages & Frameworks > PHP > Debug > Skipped Paths`

[image: PHP Storm 2016.2]

Comment: But @nwrman, this does not prevent debugger from stepping into files listed here. If script `a.php` calls some function in `b.php` which is on the skipped paths list, debugger will still walk you through it.